Why does the Rust compiler drop unused variables in the reverse order they were declared?
In the Rust book an example is provided in chapter 15 section 3 to show when Rust runs the drop function on the variables c and d.
struct CustomSmartPointer {
    data: String,
}

impl Drop for CustomSmartPointer {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping CustomSmartPointer with data `{}`!", self.data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = CustomSmartPointer {
        data: String::from("my stuff"),
    };
    let d = CustomSmartPointer {
        data: String::from("other stuff"),
    };
    println!("CustomSmartPointers created.");
}

and the output is:
CustomSmartPointers created.
Dropping CustomSmartPointer with data `other stuff`!
Dropping CustomSmartPointer with data `my stuff`!

My question is why does the rust compiler drop the variables in this order? Given that the variables are not used or referenced shouldn't they be dropped right after they are declared, and be dropped in the order they were declared?
I have also tried the same code with another declared variable.
//snip
let e = CustomSmartPointer {
    data: String::from("more stuff"),
};

and the output stays reversed
CustomSmartPointers created.
Dropping CustomSmartPointer with data `more stuff`!
Dropping CustomSmartPointer with data `other stuff`!
Dropping CustomSmartPointer with data `my stuff`!

Although the way variables are dropped reminds of how data is pushed and popped off a stack, but that should be a red herring.

"Although the way variables are dropped reminds of how data is pushed and popped off a stack, but that should be a red herring." No, that's probably it. Programming languages often store local variables on a stack.


Given that the variables are not used or referenced shouldn't they be dropped right after they are declared

No. Such behaviour would make RAII impossible. For example this:
let mut lock: Mutex<i32> = Mutex::new(1);
...
{
    let mut guard = lock.lock().unwrap();
    *guard += 1;
    // Something that doesn't reference guard
    // but needs to be run under lock
    notify_counter_update();
}

The guard here not only holds data internally, but more importantly it is a structure that unlocks the underlying lock on drop. Thanks to drop happening at the end of the scope I have this entire scope automatically under the lock/unlock process. I don't have to remember about manually unlocking the lock (which would be necessary if Rust dropped guard the moment it is no longer used, I mean: guards would be useless). Which would be very error prone, if the scope contains for example ifs or other nested scopes.
Another example, consider this:
fn custom_fn(value: &String) -> &str;
...

{
    let x = "foo".to_owned();
    let y = custom_fn(&x);
    println!("{}", y);
}

when should Rust drop x? The last time it is used, i.e. after call, but before println? What if custom_fn is implemented as
fn custom_fn(value: &String) -> &str {
    value.as_str()
}

? Dropping x before println results in println trying to access deallocated memory (remember that unlike &str the String type owns memory and deallocates it on drop). Undefined Behaviour. Crash, if you are lucky. You could argue that Rust can deduce it. But can it always deduce that? What if:
fn custom_fn(value: &String) -> &str {
    if rand() > 0.5 {
        value.as_str()
    }
    else
    {
        "baz"
    }
}

where rand() returns a random float in 0..1 range. What can Rust deduce about this case? Or even worse: what if custom_fn is an external function, not defined in Rust at all? The only correct,  consistent and easy to understand way is to drop x at the end of the scope.

and be dropped in the order they were declared?

The order is secondary, and in theory any is fine (assuming variables are independent of course). But some choice had to be made, and it is useful to have it consistent. So there are only two natural choices here: the same order as declaration or reversed.
Reversed order is more natural though. For example back to the example with locks. Assume we have two of them:
{
    let mut guard1 = lock1.lock().unwrap();
    let mut guard2 = lock2.lock().unwrap();
    // do something
}

Would you really expect lock1 to be unlocked before lock2? I think most people wouldn't. And in fact it is consistent when nesting scopes. The code above is equivalent to:
{
    let mut guard1 = lock1.lock().unwrap();
    {
        let mut guard2 = lock2.lock().unwrap();
        // do something
    }
}

which otherwise (i.e. with different order of drops) wouldn't.

RAII will be possible, as the compiler can track usages just like it can track lifetimes.

@ChayimFriedman in this simple case. Not if more code goes after *guard += 1; but which doesn't reference guard. I've updated the answer.

The case of a mutex protecting external data (or code) does exist (I even put it in my own answer), but is very rare indeed. Claiming it "would make RAII impossible" because of this case is just wrong.

@ChayimFriedman I don't know what you mean by "wrong" and why you would assume that that's the only case, or even most important case. Considering that I literally started the sentence with "For example...". Nitpicking, seriously.

"Impossible" is a strong word. The hypothetical alternate-reality Rust that tracks usage and drops immediately would still support sideeffectful RAII, it would just be less ergonomic. In your example, you'd probably have to write drop(guard) at the end of scope to force the lock to acquired up until that point.

@user4815162342 which defeats the purpose of RAII. And is error prone.

@freakish Of course it doesn't defeat the purpose of RAII, except by some narrow definition. The point of RAII is that the constructor acquires the resource and the destructor frees up the resource, which both the current and the hypothetical Rust do. And it is error prone only if you have side effects such as unsafe code. If you are actually using guard, it will get dropped when you no longer need it, and no later (or earlier). Rust could have done that, and it wouldn't have made RAII "impossible", which your answer is erroneously claiming.

@user4815162342 the real purpose of RAII is automatic resource management, especially disposal (which often is less obvious). Which by adding manual drop (or any other form of artificial lifetime extension) makes it pointless. I might as well just unlock the lock instead. And yes, it is error prone. Now I have to think were should I put the drop (or should I put it at all). Look at my second example. In practice everyone will just put it at the end. If they remember that is.

We are talking past each other. The purpose of manual drop I described is to extend the scope in the rare cases you need the drop done later for side effect. Normal code would not require a manual drop, just like it doesn't require it now.

@user4815162342 I don't know what "normal" code is supposed to mean. Either way you have two choices here: one that works always and is easy to understand, or the other which doesn't always work, requires "normal" code (whatever that means) and high level of understanding when each variable is actually going to be dropped, which is not always obvious. And compiler won't assist you. And ultimately leads to manually doing the first choice. Sorry, but that's the definition of error prone, and easy choice for me.

@freakish Normal means that doesn't rely on side effects on when an otherwise unused lock guard (or other RAII object) is dropped. But I don't even care to argue that point - my objection was regarding the claim that it would make RAII "impossible", which is patently false.

@user4815162342 yeah, it is false if you allow an incomplete, not intuitive and error prone design for RAII. But I don't.

You claim two things: that variables should be dropped after their last usage instead of at the end of the block, and that dropping should be in order instead of in reverse order. The answer to each of these claims is different.
For the first claim, variables being dropped at the end of the scope is almost a necessity.
The problem is that the compiler cannot accurately detect uses.
Even if the compiler can track lifetimes, it cannot track raw pointers. And access through them still ought to be valid.
Here's an example:
fn main() {
    let v = vec![123];
    let p: *const i32 = v.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", *p);
    }
}

With your proposed law, the compiler will drop v immediately after the as_ptr() call, but that will make p dangling and the printing UB.
What's more, sometimes even raw pointers don't signify the liveness. For example, people may use Mutex<()> to protect some external data. The compiler has no way to tie the external data with the MutexGuard; if it will drop (thus unlock) it too early, you may have data races.
About the order, reverse order is just natural. It allows you to do things like the following:
let mutex = std::sync::Mutex::new("abc".to_owned());
let lock = mutex.lock().unwrap();

The mutex and the lock are in the same block. If the mutex would be dropped earlier, this wouldn't compile since the data was freed with the mutex's drop, but the MutexGuard's destructor may access it (there is an attribute to help with cases like that - #[may_dangle], but it is unstable, unsafe and requires adjustments on the type, and won't work when the destructor actually need to access the data. Reverse order is just better).

It does not matter that the variables are unused; since you have stored them in variables they are subject to the drop rules of variables. Namely "local variables declared in a let statement are associated to the scope of the block that contains the let statement" and "When control flow leaves a drop scope, all variables associated to that scope are dropped in reverse order of declaration [...]" from destructors in the Rust Reference.
If you know they aren't used and want them to be dropped immediately, you can chose not to store them in a variable or use a _ binding (since that is not a variable):
// the value is created and dropped immediately
let _ = CustomSmartPointer {
    data: String::from("my stuff"),
};

Why are they dropped in reverse order? There is some fairly agnostic reasons in this C++ Q&A, but the gist of it is that later variables often depend on earlier variables and thus if earlier variables were destroyed earlier, then drop logic on later variables would likely to cause a data-race / conflict. This would likely appear as a borrow checker error in Rust for seemingly silly reasons.
